# How to convert JSON Array to JSON String jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function which returns me the following string

```
var inputs = [{"tag":"example"},{"tag":"test"}];
var obj = {};
$.each(inputs, function(index, item) {
    $.extend(obj, item);
});
```

I want result code

```
inputs = {'example':null,'test':null}
```

Comment: If you give your input clearly then only I can check.

Comment: with conversion you should use `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.each(inputs, function(index,item) {
    obj[item['tag']]=null;
});
```